# “USDA” is All Set to launch in Early 2023 | What services will it provide?

Tags: stablecoins

According to Emurgo, USDA will go live on the Anzens platform in Q1 2023, allowing users to tokenize their USD into USDA using credit/debit cards, wire transfers, or the conversion of ADA.

USDA is a component of Emurgo’s Anzens program, a larger scheme that would provide customers with a range of financial services and products based on Cardano.

Can some one detail the application/services these programs support?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [EMURGO's blog post](https://emurgo.io/emurgo-introduces-first-usd-backed-stablecoin-for-the-cardano-ecosystem/), the services and use cases that the Anzens program will have are:

- Managing Web3 balance sheets
- Making card payments directly with crypto
- Regulated lending and borrowing of assets
- Conversion to other stablecoins (not only USDA)
- Conversion and swaps of other cryptocurrencies
- Setting up stake pools that pay out rewards in USDA

For more information, you can check [their website](https://www.anzens.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information.

Comment: No worries! If it was helpful, you can mark the answer as accepted using the grey tick. Cheers.